# Failure when attaching PEM certificate in HttpClient request in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, ssl-certificate, pem, mtls

I need to send data to a HTTPS protected endpoint from my ASP.NET Core 6 application. It is required to attach a `.pem` certificate with a key with the `.key` extension. The anatomy of these files is the following:

mtls.pem:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
(3 times repeated)
```

mtls.key:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The certificate is attached when the client is injected, as the following:

```
services.AddHttpClient<IIntegrationClient, IntegrationClient>()
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual
        };

        var path = Path.Combine(environment.ContentRootPath, "Certificates");

        var certificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(
            Path.Combine(path, "mtls.pem"),
            Path.Combine(path, "mtls.key"));

        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

        return handler;
    });
```

However, when the `httpClient.SendAsync(request)` method is called, it throws some exceptions, remakably `Win32Exception (0x8009030E): No credentials are available in the security package`:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x8009030E): No credentials are available in the security package at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(ISSPIInterface secModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SCH_CREDENTIALS* scc)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SCH_CREDENTIALS* secureCredential) 
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandleSchCredentials(SslAuthenticationOptions authOptions)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AcquireClientCredentials(Byte[]& thumbPrint)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.GenerateToken(ReadOnlySpan`1 inputBuffer, Byte[]& output)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.NextMessage(ReadOnlySpan`1 incomingBuffer)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessBlob(Int32 frameSize)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, 
CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.HttpConnectionWaiter`1.WaitForConnectionAsync(Boolean async, CancellationToken requestCancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
...
```

I tried to:

1. I read a suggestion about converting the certificate into a PFX, like this:

```
var certificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(
    Path.Combine(path, "mtls.pem"),
    Path.Combine(path, "mtls.key"));

certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx));
```

When it is implemented, the exception is no longer thrown, but the certificate is considered invalid in the destination. `400 Bad Request - The SSL certificate error`.

2. Creating a proof of concept in a plain Console application with the same framework version of the application. No success, same results as the entire application;
3. Creating another proof of concept in a plain Node console application using `axios`. The certificate was added via the `httpsAgent` attribute. It does work, indicating the certificate is ok.

The application is using .NET 6 with ASP.NET Core 6 and the operating system is Windows 10.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of combining the .pem and .key files in your code, every time it starts, use openssl to do it. Install the resulting .pfx file in the computer's certificate store. Then use `X509Store` to find the certificate on application startup. You shouldn't be manipulating certificate data in your code if it's not the actual purpose of your application, and you sure as heck shouldn't have the files on disk, especially not under your content root.

Comment: You are not failing TLS (the SSL error).  You are failing the Authentication.  If TLS was failing you would not get the 400 error.  See following for troubleshooting : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/sslstream-troubleshooting

Comment: I'm guessing that the server needs to identify the user via the certificate, so your certificate is not valid. Possibly it fell foul of the new String Certificate Mapping rules, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5014754-certificate-based-authentication-changes-on-windows-domain-controllers-ad2c23b0-15d8-4340-a468-4d4f3b188f16 or maybe it's simply a self-signed certificate. Please indicate why you think the server should accept your certificate.

Comment: @madreflection, I might not have enough privileges on the host that this code will be deployed to modify the Certificate Store of Windows. Do you see alternatives than using the Store?

Comment: @Charlieface, you are right when you say that the server identifies me via the certificate. The reason I think the server should accept my certificate is that when I make the same request via Node.js - via axios, without certificate conversions, same machine and OS -, it is accepted with no problems.

Comment: You can add it to the User Certificate Store (which is per user), and you should be able to pick it up from there. Go to `certmgr.msc`. If you are running this under a service user account (such as an AppPool user) then run `certmgr.msc` as that user, or load via Powershell as that user

Comment: Maybe [Azure key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/certificate-scenarios)?